# How to "Bootstrapify" an existing web page?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I have some existing HTML that's not exactly mobile-friendly.  I'm looking to see if there's a kind of "conversion" process/etc. to convert an existing web page to be mobile-friendly (i.e. Bootstrap)?

Comment: Nope. It requires adding classes and probably restructuring quite a bit of the DOM of your site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a nice clean markup structure it can be fairly easy to get the overall layout responsive. You can either apply percentage values to the widths of your primary vertical elements, or you can develop a set of media queries to manage them in a stepwise fashion. Strip widths from subordinate elements to let them flow with these primary containers. That gets you far enough with modern mobile devices that you may not feel the need to go to a single-column block layout at all.

You'll probably spend most of your time doing the little things--working out a mobile navigation scheme, dealing with images like your logo on small screens, etc.

Get familiar with that Bootstrap and Foundation offer. If you think you can make use of their many elements and features, overlay one of them using their classes and data attributes for quick-n-easy conversion. If not, work up a simple grid or media query protocol like I've mentioned.

Comment: +1 -- I hope people search and find this answer in the future but oftentimes the skill set is just not there to understand what you are referring to. This is what I have done. Take the current site and find the min-width where it looks best, put ALL the css in that min-width, say 1000px, then move global styles (colors, but not floats, for example) before that media query. Put common, shared before the min-width, put not shared inside a max-width, and learn to use percentages for nearly everything.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Why not post your own answer?

Answer (score 0):

Not aware of any conversion processes to aid in converting an HTML site to a mobile friendly site, like one built on Twitter Bootstrap platform. Far as I know, it's a manual process. Start with a Twitter Bootstrap framework, and copy and paste over your HTML content, images, etc. into the Bootstrap framework and directory structure. You'll also need to map the HTML navigation over into the Bootstrap nav. On the whole, most of the existing information should map over to the Bootstrap framework, which will in the end get you a mobile-friendly website.